# Calling a Void Pointer Buffer argument throws Runtime Error

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I Have a Function Like below:

```
void Dump(uint32_t sig, const void *buf, int bytes_to_send) {
}
```

Which needs to be called from the UT code.

I tried the below code snippets to call it :

Method1:

```
  // string to char* - but thats not what I want
  string *pStr = new string("Where is my place in Memory?");
  uint32_t sig = 4;
  Dump(sig,pStr,100);
```

Method2:

```
  // char to string
  char tab[4];
  tab[0] = 'c';
  tab[1] = 'a';
  tab[2] = 't';
  tab[3] = '\0';
  Dump(4,&tab,sizeof(tab));
```

Method3:

```
  int i=0;
  char aPointer[] = "I love earth and all its creatures.";
  char *pCarrier[sizeof(aPointer)]; 
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(aPointer); i++)
      pCarrier[i] = &aPointer[i];
  Dump(4,pCarrier ,sizeof(aPointer));
```

Everything Compiles But the RunTime behavior is Errors like

```
Invalid read of size 2
==16492==    at 0x4A08DAC
==16492== Invalid read of size 8
Memcheck:Addr2
```

**Other Errors**:

```
==24108== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
```

Please share some suggestions friends!!

Comment: A bit misleading to name an array `aPointer`, don't you think?

Comment: Sorry its a typo..

Comment: Your compiler should complain about `char *pCarrier = &aPointer;`.  Please fix all compiler messages, and post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why is `buf` `const void*` rather than `const char*`, and why is `bytes_to_send` signed? Do you want to send a negative number of bytes?

Comment: @Martin : No idea.. Iam just testing by calling the function..

Comment: @ moderator: I didn't understand the reason why they voted to close. Iam raising it as a concern to unblock the query. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Method 1 won't work because `Dump()` has no idea what a `string*` is
   or what to do with it.
2. Method 2 won't work because you send the address of `tab` rather than `tab`.
3. Method 3 won't work because it's populating an array with the address of each element `aPointer`.

Try:

```
char message[] = "My message";
const size_t len = strlen(message);
Dump(4, message, len);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestion.. I will Try this...

Comment: I tried your solution and got the below error  "==24108== Use of uninitialised value of size 8"

Comment: If you compile with `-g`, you will be able to see the line numbers in the Valgrind output.

Comment: No, `aPointer` is a _not_ a pointer, it's an array of `strlen(aPointer)+1` elements (which `sizeof` correctly returns).

Comment: @zenith, you're right, I was deceived by its name.